# Java JTabbedPane can't add multiple tabs?

Tags: java, swing, text, actionlistener, jtabbedpane

I'm re doing a specific application, just a basic text editor and I remember I had tabs and a JMenu so if you went File --> New it would add or 'Open' another tab on the JTabbedPane.  But this time it's not doing it for me, could someone help?  Here is how im doing it:

```
newFile.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        tabs.addTab("new file", text);
                    }
                }
        );
```

So when it's clicked it should add another tab but it's not for some reason...
If it matters there is a default tab open at the beginning and when you click new it wipes out the old one.
Thanks for any help!  (Please ask if you need anymore explanation)
Here I uploaded my code here since the editor here kept saying I the way I was putting it in wasnt formatted correctly:
http://nardcake.com/java
There is 2 files there, one initializes it and the other is everything else
thanks!

Comment: if my answer doesn't work for you, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>try:</strike>

```
tabs.revalidate();
tabs.repaint();
```

I have removed these two lines (those two are anyhow called in the end by addTab() method), and rewritten your init.java like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()); // 1
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()); //2
            EBLFWE window = new EBLFWE();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setExtendedState( window.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
            window.setSize(1024, 728);
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

It works now. To [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872775/how-to-move-3-buttons-inside-a-window/12872821#128728219) myself:

> Every usage of Swing components must be done thorugh the Event Dispatch Thread (abbreviated [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)) or you will probably get unwanted visual effects. See [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml) for explanation.

EDIT:

All the GUI related code must be executed on the EDT. You can test if some part of your code is *run by* EDT like this:

```
 System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
```

If it prints true you are safe to do a GUI update (e.g. call methods on Swing components instances) - like in 1 or anywhere in EBLFWE class. However 2 will print false - it is because the  [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) that *runs* your program *is not* EDT.

When calling [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) you are actually placing that code to be executed (at some appropriate time the EDT sees fit) in the Event dispatch thread.

EDT does the actual painting, and a lot of other tasks, so when you call GUI update code from another [thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) you can mess up the order and get unwanted visual apperance.

Comment: so in the action listener do `tabs.revalidate();`?  I did but it didn't do anything...  Somewhere else?

Comment: yes, just below the addTab  add *both*  tabs.revalidate(); tabs.repaint(); If it doesn't work you ll have to post [all the relevant code](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Nope, Ok I post it all in the question here

Comment: the interesting thing is though, that it works even as you posted, that's why you must know swing well before using it - cause it ll look spuroius and not even always :) pls feedback.

Comment: Well thanks for helping but im not quite sure exactly what you did still, a bit more explanation please?